# Check if other file then request exists in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish the following in a .htaccess file, but can't seem to get it to work...

- if file ~/maintenance.htm exists, temporarily redirect to that file (R=302) and append the current query string (QSA), end (l)
- if maintenance.htm file is requested (refresh by user) and exists, show the file, query string and end (L, QSA)
- it maintenance.htm file is requested (refresh by user) and no longer exists, redirect to index.php (R=301) and append the query string (QSA), end (L)

The first step is where it goes wrong, I can't seem to figure out a way to check whether or not a file exists, that is not currently being requested. 
I've been looking at a lot of different things, also RewriteMaps, but can't seem to get to redirect from rewritemaps, or that's just not clear to me. 
For instance if I write as simple perl script that checks if a file exists, how do I get the result from that to whether or not to redirect?

Thanks for any help/tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have already, but this should work.  You were probably getting the 500 error when using the `-f` because of a internal redirect loop.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.htm
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.htm -f
RewriteRule (.*) /maintenance.htm [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /maintenance.htm
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.htm !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfect, I just forgot the first RewriteCond. Added some more options to the RewriteRules though (R=301/302,QSA,NE,L).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will help to check for file existance

> '-f' (is regular file) Treats the
>   TestString as a pathname and tests
>   whether or not it exists, and is a
>   regular file.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: The problem with that is that it checks the REQUEST_FILENAME - which is index.php, and which will exist. It should check, when requesting index.php, whether or not maintenance.htm exists. That is the tricky part ;) Already tried with RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.htm -f to check whether or not it is a file, but that gives http 500 ;)